# distribution certificate does not match

Tags: iphone, xcode, certificate, distribution

As you can see on the screenshot i ve got my developer and distributions profile but i can use the distributions .
I just want to submit a app to the store.
Maybe you can assist me what i ve done wrong and why Xcode is not using my profile

[screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/659484/screen.png)

```
iPhone Distribution (no profiles currently match)
```

I downloaded the certificate  - after i uploaded the keychain (assistant stuff) and added the it to my keychain

Comment: The screenshot is gone so I downvoted this question.  Next time, please use Stackoverflow's image uploader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing it the provisioning profile, not the certificate. You should generate a provisioning profile for distribution, and add it to Xcode's organizer.

Comment: well that works now :) but no i can't creat a archive any more any idea?

Comment: Select "Device" instead of "Simulator" ?

Answer (score -2):

Try by update the APPID in the App-info.plist file .Some time it may be due to this